# df -h show system full even after clearing bloated log folder

Tags: linux, memory-usage, df

I had my php_errors.log file fill up the system, I deleted the error logs, but when I type

```
df -h www/folder_name
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
bindfs          7.8G  7.4G  379M  96% /www/folder_name
```

How do I clear it up

Comment: Did you restart the process that opened those files?

Comment: You had better use `cd /www/folder_name; du -sh *` to check which files cost such much on your disk.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of [this site search](https://serverfault.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5blinux%5d%20%22disk%20full%22). This question has been asked and answered many times already.

Answer (score 0):

Try walking the directory tree using:

`du -h --max-depth=1 /www/folder_name`

to figure out which directories are using the most space.

Comment: the sum total of all the files don't add up to 1.2GB  this is why I'm worried

 [   473M    ./vendor
    12K     ./nbproject
    32K     ./bootstrap
    12K     ./tests
    468K    ./database
    6.1M    ./.git
    34M     ./storage
    25M     ./public
    1.8M    ./resources
    132K    ./config
    796K    ./app
    611M    .
]

Answer (score 0):

"df -h" only shows you the free space, which is has done. You have 379M free on that filesystem.

You may want to try something like "du -sh /www/folder_name/*" to determine what is using the space in that folder.